# mechanism of automatic reference counting

Tags: memory-management, swift3, automatic-ref-counting

I was reading about automatic reference counting and initializers and deinitializers
and I was doing below practical

```html
  class person
    {
        var first_name:String?
        var last_name:String?
        
        
        init(firstname name:String,lastname lastname:String) {
            
            first_name = name
            self.speciality = speciality
            
            
        }
        
        deinit {
            print("object destroyed")
        }

    }
```

I have made one class like above and then I crated instance like

```
let newPerson =person.init(firstname:"string1" lastname:"string2")
```

now my question is how this object is going to destroyed according to ARC since the person I have created is constant so I can't assign it to other object it gives me this error

```html
error: cannot assign to value: 'newPerson' is a 'let' constant
   newPerson = nil
~~~~~~~~~~ ^
```

but if I do this then deinit method is called

```
var newPerson = person(firstname:"string1",lastname:"string2")
```

and then if I do

```
newPerson = person(firstname:"string2",lastname:"string3")
```

then deinit method is called so what is going on here can any one explain me in brief

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `newPerson` is a non-optional `Person`, you can't assign `nil` to it. But to deinitialize the object (call it A), you don't need to. That will happen when `newPerson` goes out of scope (e.g. the function it was declared in goes out of scope).

When you construct a new person (call it B) and assign it to `newPerson`, the reference `newPerson` had to A is overwritten. Since `newPerson` was the last strong reference to A, A is deinitialized